# Compare one Dictionary Key with another Dictionary Value and create a new Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to create a New dictionory by comparing one dictionry key with another dictionory value

i tried with following code but it's not giving expected results

```
dictionary1 = {a: 1, b: 2}
dictionary2 = {2: d, 1: e}
common_pairs = dict()
for key in dictionary1:
    if (key in dictionary2 and dictionary1[key] == dictionary2[key]):
      common_pairs[key] = dictionary1[key]
print(common_pairs)
```

I am expecting output like below

```
{a: e, b: d}
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: chars in dictionnaries (a, b, d, e) must be quoted ('a',' b', 'd', 'e'), unless you refer to variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dictionary comprehension

```
# Valid dictionaries (i.e. key strings must be quoted, thus 'a' not a, etc.)
dictionary1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dictionary2 = {2: 'd', 1: 'e'}


# Dictionary comprehension (replace value in dictionary1 with lookup
# in dictionary2
result = {k:dictionary2[v] for k, v in dictionary1.items() if v in dictionary2}
print(result) # Output: {'a': 'e', 'b': 'd'}

# Alternative--place None when value not in dicstionary2
dictionary1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3} # value 3 not in dictionary2
dictionary2 = {2: 'd', 1: 'e'}
result = {k:dictionary2.get(v, None) for k, v in dictionary1.items()}
# Output: {'a': 'e', 'b': 'd', 'c': None}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without dict comprehension :

```py
dictionary1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dictionary2 = {2: 'd', 1: 'e'}
common_pairs = dict()

for key in dictionary1:
    common_pairs[key] = dictionary2[dictionary1[key]]
print(common_pairs)  # {'a': 'e', 'b': 'd'}
```

Comment: THanks bro..but i can approve only one